# Задание расположения блоков, без использования свойства height

Tags: веб-дизайн, css

Как делается вот такое расположение блоков (свойство css float left)?
[image]

То есть, не указывая height? Подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: > не указывая height

Если вообще не использовать height на странице, то думаю что вариантов нет.

Comment: а как тогда эта вещь делается?

Comment: где-то я такое видел, не помню и найти не могу...

Comment: Единственный вариант, который я вижу - делать колонны (в вашем случае четыре штуки) и внутри них отображать блоки друг под другом.

Comment: @zhekonya, сложность задачи не в том, как расположить блоки в указанном порядке, а в том, что (*повторюсь*) вы исключаете возможность использования высоты для этих блоков. На рисунке они все у вас разной высоты. Как же это соотношение можно задать в разметке, если свойство height исключено из оборота?

Comment: ясно...всем спасибо! Нашел выход из ситуации...колонны не получилось бы сделать, там вывод из базы(((

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Когда я пытался так сделать на одно проекте, то пришлось делать это на jquery, вот [ссылка](http://masonry.desandro.com/) на библиотеку. Там есть примеры - все довольно просто. Под ваши задачи думаю подойдет (после подключения самой библиотеки и jquery) вот такой код -

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box'
});
```

где `#container` - это идентификатор блока в котором лежат блоки, а `.box` - класс для самих блоков. Вот [пример](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html) того, что примерно получится.

Answer (score 3):

Используя Padding, Margin, контент внутри блока, положить картинки с определённой высотой?

Вот если можем использовать контент то так:

http://jsfiddle.net/W8D7w/30/